# What is the origin of the Latin suffix -ela?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

Wiktionary has an entry for the Latin suffix "-ēla," used in words such as "tēla" and "candēla," as a suffix that "forms abstract nouns from verbs, often specifically deponent verbs."

Where does this suffix come from, etymologically?

Comment: FWIW, Weiss's historical grammar of Latin (p. 301) says the etymology is unclear. (*Tēla* doesn't contain this suffix, but a different suffix -*la*.)

Comment: potentially a link to the -l- past participle? It's passive in Armenian which could explain its use with deponents in Latin